# Error in future covariates when the length of the series and covariates are the same in Darts package

Tags: python, time-series, arima

Model fit with AUtoARIMA with covariates throws an error - below is the code I tried.
"The provided `future_covariates` series must contain at least the same time steps/" "indices as the target `series`.",logger=logger,  self._expect_future_covariates = True AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'slice_intersect'.

```py
df= pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df_train=df.iloc[0:17,:]
df_test=df.iloc[16:,:]

timeseries = darts.TimeSeries.from_series(df_train['y'])
timeseries_flag_past=darts.TimeSeries.from_series(df_train['flag'])

print (len(timeseries)) # 17
print (len(timeseries_flag_past)) # 17

timeseries_flag_future=darts.TimeSeries.from_series(df_test['flag'])

## Error in the code below
model = AutoARIMA(lags=[-1],lags_future_covariates=[-1])
modelaa=model.fit(timeseries,future_covariates=[timeseries_flag_past])
```